# Reversing a string in C iteratively

Tags: c, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string in C, I was able to accomplish this but not without a side effect that I don't quite understand. Here is my code to reverse a string:

```
void reverseString(char *toReverse, char *reverse) {
    int i = strlen(toReverse);
    int counter = 0;
    for (i; toReverse[counter] != '\0'; i--) {
        reverse[i] = toReverse[counter];
        counter++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char reverse[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
    reverse[strlen(reverse)] = '\0';
    reverseString(argv[1], reverse);
    printf("The reverse string is '%s'", reverse);
}
```

When give a string this correctly reverse the string but also adds some additional data, for example:

Given the string `abc123` the string `321cbaub◄¥u"ñç«` is returned

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Insread of:'reverse[strlen(reverse)] = '\0';' You need 'reverse[strlen(argv[1])] = '\0';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- The way you set the null terminator for `reversed` in `main` is incorrect because you use `strlen(reverse)` when `reverse` is still uninitialized. That's the main reason you get garbage output, because the null terminator is not set at the correct offset, but this is undefined behavior, passing an uninitialized array to `strlen` could have worse consequences.
- The null terminator should be set in `reverseString` for consistency and simplicity.
- You should decrement `i` before copying the character, otherwise you create the reversed string shifted one position to the right.
- You should end the `printf` format string with a linefeed
- `main` should return `0`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void reverseString(const char *toReverse, char *reverse) {
    int i = strlen(toReverse);
    int counter = 0;
    reverse[i] = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
    while (toReverse[counter] != '\0') {
        reverse[--i] = toReverse[counter++];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char reverse[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
    reverseString(argv[1], reverse);
    printf("The reverse string is '%s'\n", reverse);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give a null termination `\0` in your `reverse` string to use `printf` with `%s` format to print the string you reversed correctly.

```
void reverseString(char* toReverse, char* reverse) {
    int i = strlen(toReverse);
    int counter = 0;
    for (i; toReverse[counter] != '\0'; i--) {
        reverse[i] = toReverse[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    reverse[counter] = '\0'; //add this
}
```

Also, sometimes for dynamically allocated stuff, it would be best practice to use malloc:

```
reverse = (char*)malloc(i + 1);
```

Becomes something like this:

```
void reverseString(char* toReverse, char* reverse) {
    int i = strlen(toReverse);
    int counter = 0;
    reverse = (char*)malloc(i + 1);
    for (i; toReverse[counter] != '\0'; i--) {
        reverse[i] = toReverse[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    reverse[counter] = '\0'; //add this
}
```

Comment: Why use memory allocation in `reverseString`?  `i` must be decremented before the first loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I will say `reverse[counter] = '\0';` add this in the function it self.
That will look like

```
void reverseString(char* toReverse, char* reverse) {
    int i = strlen(toReverse);
    int counter = 0;
    for (i; toReverse[counter] != '\0'; i--) 
    {
        reverse[i] = toReverse[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    reverse[counter] = '\0'; //add this
}
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

Your string isn't null-terminated, that's why you're getting rubbish after the reversed string.

So, you should first do `reverse[i+1]=0;` in your `reverseString`.